# Upgraded to Xcode 9 Swift 4. Now Auto-Layout is whacked

Tags: autolayout, xcode9

Just updated to Xcode 9 and converted my project to Swift 4 but one of my app screens with a tableview has begun to show as such:

[image]

I've removed all but one stack view and just placed all my elements in that one stack view with the constraints clipped to 0,0,0,0

it should look like this:

[image]

What's going on here?

Comment: Should I do that? So what?

Comment: It's not clear from your first image, what the issue is?  Are you using MapKit?  It appears that way from image 1, but not included in image 2.

Comment: Sorry about that. Map kit is fine. It’s just that tableview cells are not showing the content as shown. But on build it shows the top image.

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue. Have you solved it?

Comment: @ikel haven’t had time yet. I’ll comment when I do.

Comment: @ikel, looks like the trailing constraint was bounding to my "location image" instead of the content view.

Answer (score 0):

This was a simple fix once I sat down and looked at it with fresh eyes.

Make sure your constraints are bounding to a view instead of another item in the view.

I cleared constraints and added a stack-view then added constraints carefully making sure it was bounding to a view.

[image: Use Content View]